# I have created a webpage that will factorialize a number. I have created that function. Now I need to create a function that will show my math.

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

Can anyone help me to do this? The function is empty below and I am unsure how to proceed. I have the factorized number showing on the webpage now I would like the math to show before it. Something like this;

A user inputs: 3
Our site outputs: "1 x 2 x 3 = 6"

```
function factorialize(num) {
 var total = 1;
 if (num > 1) {
  for (var i = 1; i <= num; i += 1) {
  total *= i;
  }
}
 return total;
}

function showMath() {

};


$(document).ready(function() {
  $("form#new-item").submit(function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   var userInput = parseInt($("input#input1").val());
   var result = factorialize(userInput);
   var myWork = showMath(userInput);
   // var
   $("#output").text(myWork + " = " + result);


 });
});
```

Comment: Rather than using a separate function, in the loop of your `factorialize()` function you could build up a string `math += " x " + i`.

Comment: I am sorry I am just a beginner. Where in the loop would I inert that line of code?

Comment: Add it before or after `total *= i`. And add `var math = "1";` before the loop and change the loop to start at `var i = 2`. The function could then return `math + " = " + total`. Having said that, Malk's answer below is a much better alternative, although I realise `.reduce()` can be a bit confusing for beginners.

Answer (score 1):

You should build up an array of all the factors. Then it is easy to `reduce()` the array to a single value or `join()` it into a string.

```
function toFactorialArray(num){
  var n = num, 
      arr = [n];

  while (--n) arr.push(n);
  return arr;
}

function getResult(arr){
    return arr.reduce( 
        function( memo, current ) {
           return memo * current
        }, 1
    );
}

function getWork(arr){
   return arr.reverse().join(' * ');
}





$(document).ready(function() {
  $("form#new-item").submit(function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   var userInput = parseInt($("input#input1").val());
   var factors = toFactorialArray(userInput);
   var result = getResult(factors);
   var myWork = getWork(factors);

   $("#output").text(myWork + " = " + result);


 });
});
```

Comment: Thank you that was very helpful.